# ASP.NET Core default authentication scheme is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm trying to set my custom authentication handler as default, so that I can use `[Authorize]` attribute without explicitly specifying the scheme. Here is the Program.cs code:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(Constants.Auth.SchemeNames.MyScheme) // <-- why doesn't it work?
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthenticationSchemeOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>(Constants.Auth.SchemeNames.MyScheme, null);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

But the `CustomAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()` method is called only if I specify my scheme name in the attributes explicitly:
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Constants.Auth.SchemeNames.MyScheme)]`

Why is the default schema name not applied in the  `AddAuthentication` method?

ASP.NET Core ver = 6.0.8

---

**P.S.**

---

I've set up the authorization default policy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(Constants.Auth.SchemeNames.MyScheme);
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    cfg.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});
```

And now my scheme is used by default as I wanted, but I still can't understand what is the role of the `string defaultScheme` parameter in the `AddAuthentication` method:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, string defaultScheme)
```

Now it works even if I don't pass the `defaultScheme` to it at all.

Another strange thing is that even when my `CustomAuthenticationHandler` is not called, the `[Authorize]` attribute still seems to work somehow since the 401 code is returned. It looks like some default authentication scheme is in charge even if I haven't set anything except my custom one.

Comment: Some applications might need to support multiple types of authentication, `AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, string defaultScheme)` provides a way to specify the default authentication scheme to use when configuring authentication. Can check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0